# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Everything runs properly from nodemon until I go to the browser to register and got the error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
When I decided to comment the if("req.body.password.length > 4) the registration didn't work complaining password didn't match. 
Please help am very new to Node

https://gist.github.com/dngoyb/de020c2686a1104af748593d37e0e082

this is the full error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at router.post (/home/zidiou/Documents/Vidjot/Vidjot/routes/users.js:26:28)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/zidiou/Documents/Vidjot/Vidjot/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/zidiou/Documents/Vidjot/Vidjot/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/zidiou/Documents/Vidjot/Vidjot/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/zidiou/Documents/Vidjot/Vidjot/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/zidiou/Documents/Vidjot/Vidjot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/zidiou/Documents/Vidjot/Vidjot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/zidiou/Documents/Vidjot/Vidjot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/zidiou/Documents/Vidjot/Vidjot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/zidiou/Documents/Vidjot/Vidjot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/zidiou/Documents/Vidjot/Vidjot/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/zidiou/Documents/Vidjot/Vidjot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/zidiou/Documents/Vidjot/Vidjot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/zidiou/Documents/Vidjot/Vidjot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/zidiou/Documents/Vidjot/Vidjot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/zidiou/Documents/Vidjot/Vidjot/app.js:59:4
```

Comment: req.body.password is not defined **yet**. this is probably due to async behaviour of node.js. my recommendation is to look at callback functions, to make sure, that you already received the data you wanted. please provide more code so we can actually help.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, How do i then define the password?

Comment: on your html form, you need to post the data to the server. this is how i have done it about 1 year ago, **i don't know if this is still up-to-date** `form(action="", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")`

Comment: I would also suggest that before directly checking the length please check the object property existence with either **Object.hasOwnProperty('property')**

Answer (score 0):

**Its important that you've set up your HTML correctly, so the server knows which data is accesable in the body.**

This code worked for me 1 year ago, in the JS file, there are some sdk's you don't need, just ignore them, and try to set it up to work for your needs.

HTML:

```
  form(action="", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
    label(class="label", for="name") User:
    input(class="input", name="name")
    label(class="label", for="passwort") Passwort:
    input(class="input", type="password", name="passwort")
    input#button(type="submit", value="OK")
```

JS

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();
var wait = require('wait.for');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var json2pdf = require('json2pdf');
var fs = require('fs');

    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: 'XXX',
      secretAccessKey: 'XXX',
      region: 'eu-central-1'
    });

    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    app.use(session({
      secret: 'test',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: { secure: false}
    }))


    app.set('view engine', 'pug');
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));
    app.use(upload.array());



              app.post("/", function(req, res) {
                  ssn = req.session;

              // DATABASE QUERY
              var user = {
                TableName: "user-table",
                KeyConditionExpression: "#usr = :user",
                ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                  "#usr": "User",
                },
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                  ":user": req.body.name
                },
              };

              docClient.query(user, function(err, data) {
                if (data.Count == 0 || req.body.passwort != data.Items[0].Passwort) {
                // do stuff here
```

Comment: adding (enctype="multipart/form-data") to the code just made all the fields undefined